# SASS Global Variables + Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

I am using Rails 3.1RC4 with default SASS setup. I have the following files

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

**_variables.css.scss**

```
$var1 : somevalue;
...
```

**site_layout.css.scss**

```
@import "variables";
... Some Sass Code
```

But I can't access the variables defined in _variables.css.scss in site_layout. What am I doing wrong? Rails is apparently finding the variables file since it doesn't throw a "file not found" error, which it does if I change the import filename. Still the vars are not carried over.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with a mixin stored in a partial.  Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: No I haven't. For now I commented out the require statements in my application.css.scss and @import all my other sass files manually. That's working fine, but hopefully it's only a temporary solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be fixed with the latest release of rails & sprockets. In your gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git", :branch => "3-1-stable"
```

Answer (score -3):

The first part of your question (the `application.css.scss` code snippet) doesn't seem to have any relevance here, since it's just commented-out code, so I'll skip that part.

For the second code snippet, I don't believe SASS is set up to import a "partial" quite like you're doing here. You'd be better off doing something like this:

**_variables.scss** (Renamed from **_variables.css.scss**):

```
$var1: somevalue;
```

Note that the underscore in your filename is not required like it would be for a Ruby partial. You can just as easily name it `variables.scss` as long as you change the import statement to `@import "variables";`

**site_layout.scss** (Renamed from **site_layout.css.scss**)

```
@import "_variables";

.test_thingy {
  color: $var1;
  }
```

This will generate a `site_layout.css` file that contains the following code replacement:

```
.test_thingy {
  color: somevalue; }
```

Note that there's no need to have files named like `filename.css.scss` like you would with HAML/ERB files. Simply name the file what you want it to be. For example, `filename.scss` will cause SASS to generate a CSS file called `filename.css` automatically.

Comment: The `application.css.scss` file does have relevance.  The commented code is where you configure Sprockets.  The rest of your solution didn't work for me either.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The underscore is a way to define sass partials as described here: http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html.

filename.css.scss is the Rails 3.1 default filename so I'll stick with that. I think you might have misunderstood. This is not about the sass in general, it's about Rails 3.1 in particular.

Comment: @helixed, not sure why it didn't work for you, but my answer is tested.

Comment: Sure, your answer works fine when using the standalone sass gem (which never was a problem), but it doesn't work with rails 3.1 and sprockets.

Comment: @Denny, looks like I misunderstood the intention of your question, then. It appeared to me a question about SASS in general, not a particular flavor, and I didn't notice a reference to Sprockets at all. I'll be curious to see what the actual answer turns out to be.